# Criar strcut resultante em C

Tags: c, struct

Estou fazendo um exercício em que o usuário insere os dados de um veículo (marca, ano, preço) em uma `struct`.
Após isso, o usuário insere um valor.
A `struct` resultante deve mostrar apenas os dados dos veículos que estejam abaixo do valor inserido pelo usuário.

A IDE mostra que existem os seguintes erros:
1. no primeiro bloco negrito: -variável resultado(que seria a struct resultante) criada, mas nao usada
2. no segundo bloco negrito: (carro*)&resultado é um ponteiro (não entendi onde é ponteiro, uma vez que  eu não inseri e não vi necessidade, já que criei uma estrutura resultante)
3. no terceiro bloco negrito: comentário igual ao anterior

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct{
char marca[15];
int ano;
float preco;
}carro;
void cabecalho();
int main(){
carro filtrar[5], **resultado[5];**
float preco_escolhido;
int cont = 0;

cabecalho();

for (int i = 0 ; i <5 ; i++){
printf("Insira o marca do veículo: ");
fflush(stdout);
fgets(filtrar[i].marca, 15, stdin);
fflush(stdout);

printf("Insira o ano do veículo: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &filtrar[i].ano);

while (isdigit(filtrar[i].ano)){
printf("Insira o ano do veículo: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &filtrar[i].ano);
}

printf("Insira o preço do veículo: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%f", &filtrar[i].preco);

while (!isdigit(filtrar[i].preco)){
printf("Insira o preço do veículo: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%f", &filtrar[i].preco);
}

getchar();

}

printf("Insira o valor máximo que deseja pagar: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%f", &preco_escolhido);

//o código abaixo deveria inserir o valor da estrutura geral, na estrutura com a especificação,
//no caso o valor menor que o escolhido pelo usuário.

for (int i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++){
if (filtrar[i].preco <= preco_escolhido){
**resultado.marca[cont] = filtrar[i].marca;
resultado.ano[cont] = filtrar[i].ano;
resultado.preco[cont] = filtrar[i].preco;**
cont++;
}
}


printf("\nForam encontrado(s) %d veículo(s) abaixo de R$ %.2f.\n",cont, preco_escolhido);

for (int i = 0 ; i <cont ; i++){
printf("==== Veículos encontrados abaixo de R$ %.2f======\n",preco_escolhido);
**printf("Modelo: %s\n",resultado.marca[i]);
printf("Ano: %d\n",resultado.ano[i]);
printf("Preço: %.2ff\n",resultado.preco[i]);**
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Este trecho: `while (isdigit(filtrar[i].ano)){ printf("Insira o ano do veículo: "); fflush(stdout); scanf("%d", &filtrar[i].ano); }`, não tem sentido, idem para preco. A função `isdigit`verifica se o **caractere** informado como parâmetro é um dígito.

Answer (score 1):

Pacoca,

Existem diversos problemas em seu código, vamos em partes:

A utilização da função `isdigit`, essa função recebe um inteiro e você está enviando até mesmo float para ela:

```
while (!isdigit(filtrar[i].preco)){
```

---

Existe uma duplicidade de código quanto a pedir o preço e o ano do carro:

```
printf("Insira o ano do veículo: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &filtrar[i].ano);

while (isdigit(filtrar[i].ano)){
  printf("Insira o ano do veículo: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%d", &filtrar[i].ano);
}

printf("Insira o preço do veículo: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%f", &filtrar[i].preco);

while (!isdigit(filtrar[i].preco)){
  printf("Insira o preço do veículo: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%f", &filtrar[i].preco);
}
```

---

Você tentou acessar as propriedades da estrutura no array de forma incorreta, aqui:

```
resultado.marca[cont] = filtrar[i].marca;
resultado.ano[cont] = filtrar[i].ano;
resultado.preco[cont] = filtrar[i].preco;
```

E aqui também:

```
printf("Modelo: %s\n",resultado.marca[i]);
printf("Ano: %d\n",resultado.ano[i]);
printf("Preço: %.2ff\n",resultado.preco[i]);
```

Veja que em ambos os casos, você inverteu, colocando o ponto para acessar a propriedade antes de acessar o índice no array, o correto seria:

```
resultado[cont].preco = filtrar[i].preco;
```

---

Existe um pequeno detalhe na impressão do valor de float, onde você repetiu o F:

```
printf("Preço: %.2ff\n",resultado.preco[i]);
```

Nesse caso é apenas uma questão visual, basta remover um f.

---

Por fim temos a atribuição do array de char (Já corrigindo a parte de acesso ao array):

```
resultado[cont].marca = filtrar[i].marca;
```

Isso não é possível, a marca é um array de char, para efetuar essa cópia de valores, você pode utilizar da função `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(resultado[cont].marca, filtrar[i].marca);
```

---

Corrigindo todos esses detalhes, o código ficou da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct{
  char marca[15];
  int ano;
  float preco;
} carro;

void cabecalho();

int main(){
  carro filtrar[5], resultado[5];
  float preco_escolhido;
  int cont = 0;

  cabecalho();

  for (int i = 0 ; i <5 ; i++){
    printf("Insira o marca do veículo: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(filtrar[i].marca, 15, stdin);
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("Insira o ano do veículo: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &filtrar[i].ano);

    printf("Insira o preço do veículo: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%f", &filtrar[i].preco);

    getchar();
  }

  printf("Insira o valor máximo que deseja pagar: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%f", &preco_escolhido);

  //o código abaixo deveria inserir o valor da estrutura geral, na estrutura com a especificação,
  //no caso o valor menor que o escolhido pelo usuário.

  for (int i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++){
    if (filtrar[i].preco <= preco_escolhido){
      // resultado[cont].marca = filtrar[i].marca;
      strcpy(resultado[cont].marca, filtrar[i].marca);
      resultado[cont].ano = filtrar[i].ano;
      resultado[cont].preco = filtrar[i].preco;
      cont++;
    }
  }

  printf("\nForam encontrado(s) %d veículo(s) abaixo de R$ %.2f.\n",cont, preco_escolhido);

  for (int i = 0 ; i <cont ; i++){
    printf("==== Veículos encontrados abaixo de R$ %.2f======\n",preco_escolhido);
    printf("Modelo: %s\n",resultado[i].marca);
    printf("Ano: %d\n",resultado[i].ano);
    printf("Preço: %.2f\n",resultado[i].preco);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

> Veja um exemplo online desse código, onde comentei a função cabecalho,
>   pois você não colocou o corpo da mesma no exemplo:
>
> https://repl.it/repls/MotherlyHuskySystemadministrator